# how it possible to search in atom or sublime text with Logical Operators

Tags: find, sublimetext2, atom-editor

I wan't to know how can i use Logical Operators like

> & (and)

or

> || (or)

in find and replace panel in sublime or atom editor.[image]

tanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Regular Expressions (It's going to be the symbol at the bottom right that looks like `.*`), and then you can do something like `@media|span` in the search bar.